# how to send data to servlet from android application using httppost method?

Tags: android, servlets, http-post

i'm trying to send string data to servlet from android application,but i got null value in the servlet.
here i'm providing my code

Android code is:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8081/HttpGetServlet/HttpGetServlet");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", password));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Sevlet Code is:

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloWorldServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponseresponse)throwsServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String fname = (String) request.getParameter("param1");

        out.println("Hello my 1st name is : "+fname);
        String lname = (String) request.getParameter("lastName");
        out.println("Hello my last name is : "+lname);

    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            String json_array = request.getParameter("username");
            out.println("hi ::::::::::"+json_array);
    }
}
```

Any one have idea please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You set parameters `Email` and `Passwd` but try to read `username`. It is clear, that this will be `null`.